# I've suspended with the wrong keyboard layout, how to log in again?

Tags: suspend, keyboard-layout, lock-screen

I use 2 keyboard layouts de1 and de2. Regularly, I try out d2 and close the lid. Upon reopening I need to log in again but I can only do so via de2.
I can click on the little indicator to switch between de1 and de2 but the layout stays the same (I can tell from the dead keys).
I can also click on "switch user" which opens up the regular log in screen. There I can change the layout but entering the password only brings me back to the other login screen again.

Comment: Try using the keyboard shortcut for layout change. In my computer it is Super+Space. Super key usually has Windows logo on it. Depending on the version of Ubuntu you have your shortcut may be different.

Comment: @user68186 For me it's Shift+Space and doesn't work either